# how to load files with different delimiter each time in piglatin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Data from input sources have different delimiters like , OR ; .Sometime it may be , sometimes it may be ; .But PigStorage function accepts only single argument as delimiter at a time. How to load this kind of data [ with delimiter , OR ; ]

Comment: how do you know what is the delimiter? can two lines in one file have different delimiters?

Comment: we get files with either , OR ; as delimiter. No, two lines in one file have same delimiter. All records/lines will have same delimiter in a file.

Comment: you could pass the delimiter as a parameter to the pig script and call it with the specific one.

Comment: if it is either , OR ; how to pass delimiter? PigStorage accepts only single delimiter.

Comment: how do you tell whether it's , or ;? Separate folder? File names?

Comment: I know the file name with specific prefix have specific delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

Can you check if this works for you?

1. It will work all the input files with different delimiter
2. It will work same file with different delimiter also.

You can add as many delimiters inside character class `[,:,]`

Example:

```
input1.txt
1,2,3,4

input2.txt
a-b-c-d

input3.txt
100:200:300:400

input4.txt
100,aaa-200:b

PigScript:
A = LOAD 'input*' AS line;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(.*)[,:-](.*)[,:-](.*)[,:-](.*)'))  AS (f1,f2,f3,f4);
DUMP B;

Output:
(1,2,3,4)
(a,b,c,d)
(100,200,300,400)
(100,aaa,200,b)
```

Comment: Can you explain how regex works here? and why [,:-] is repeated thrice??

Answer (score 0):

```
A = LOAD '/some/path/COMMA-DELIM-PREFIX*' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:chararray, ...);
B = LOAD '/some/path/SEMICOLON-DELIM-PREFIX*' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (f1:chararray, ...);

C = UNION A,B;
```

Comment: Thanks Fred. I have standard prefixes in filenames (QWERTY_123,POIUY_029 etc.,) which have same delimiters all the time. QWERTY -> ,POIUY -> ;

I developed a udf which takes prefix and tells the delimiter. Now how to read files names in pig so that I split prefix and get delimiter

Comment: Depending on how many prefixes there are and how often they change, i'd either hardcode it as described above or, if that is too cumbersome, extend the class PigStorage and have the logic there. Does that help?

Comment: I think custom loader is the only way. Fred,  schema of A and B is different,Union doesn't work for here.How can I save A nd B into separate files?

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to write your own custom loader for delimiter .

Steps for writing custom loader :

As of 0.7.0, Pig loaders extend the LoadFunc abstract class.This means they need to override 4 methods:

    getInputFormat() this method returns to the caller an instance of the InputFormat that the loader supports. The actual load process needs an instance to use at load time, and doesn't want to place any constraints on how that instance is created.
    prepareToRead() is called prior to reading a split. It passes in the reader used during the reads of the split, as well as the actual split. The implementation of the loader usually keeps the reader, and may want to access the actual split if needed.
    setLocation() Pig calls this to communicate the load location to the loader, which is responsible for passing that information to the underlying InputFormat object. This method can be called multiple times, so there should be no state associated with the method (unless that state gets reset when the method is called).
    getNext() Pig calls this to get the next tuple from the loader once all setup has been done. If this method returns a NULL, Pig assumes that all  information in the split passed via the prepareToRead() method has been processed. 


please find the code 


package Pig;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.pig.LoadFunc;
import org.apache.pig.PigException;
import org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException;
import org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigSplit;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;

public class CustomLoader extends LoadFunc {

     private String DELIM = ",";
     private static final int DEFAULT_LIMIT = 226;
     private int limit = DEFAULT_LIMIT;
     private RecordReader reader;
     private List <Integer>indexes;
     private TupleFactory tupleFactory;




     public CustomLoader(String delimter) {
            this.DELIM = delimter;

        }

     @Override
     public InputFormat getInputFormat() throws IOException {
       return new TextInputFormat();

     }




     @Override
     public Tuple getNext() throws IOException {
      Tuple tuple = null;
      List values = new ArrayList();
      tupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
      try {
       boolean notDone = reader.nextKeyValue();
       if (!notDone) {
           return null;
       }
       Text value = (Text) reader.getCurrentValue();

       if(value != null) {
        String parts[] = value.toString().split(DELIM);


         for (int index=0 ;index< parts.length;index++) {


             if(index > limit) {
          throw new IOException("index "+index+ "is out of bounds: max index = "+limit);
         } else {
          values.add(parts[index]);
         }
         }

        tuple = tupleFactory.newTuple(values);
       }

      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       // add more information to the runtime exception condition. 
       int errCode = 6018;
                String errMsg = "Error while reading input";
                throw new ExecException(errMsg, errCode,
                        PigException.REMOTE_ENVIRONMENT, e);
      }

      return tuple;

     }

     @Override
     public void prepareToRead(RecordReader reader, PigSplit pigSplit)
       throws IOException {
      this.reader = reader; // note that for this Loader, we don't care about the PigSplit.
     }

     @Override
     public void setLocation(String location, Job job) throws IOException {
      FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, location); // the location is assumed to be comma separated paths. 

     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    } 



create a jar file 

register '/home/impadmin/customloader.jar' ;


load '/pig/u.data' using Pig.CustomLoader('::') as (id,mov_id,rat,timestamp);

data sets 

196::242::3::881250949
186::302::3::891717742
22::377::1::878887116
244::51::2::880606923
166::346::1::886397596
298::474::4::884182806
115::265::2::881171488
253::465::5::891628467
305::451::::886324817
6::86::3::883603013


Now you can specify any delimiter you want
```

Comment: Thank you. But my question was to know how to load files with different delimiters dynamically. eg., :: can be either ; OR , OR -

Comment: you need to specify the delimiter while loading the pig loader either you use default pigstorage or custom loader if you want to use one character or 2 character and moreover when you will load a file that file would be separated by one delimiter ,this is not valid case where one field separated with one delimiter other with different in same file ,let me know your thoughts

Comment: 1. Each file has only one delimiter [ either , OR ; OR tab ]
2. I know how to pass delimiter to PigStorage or custom loader.
My scenario is : My input files are delimited either by , OR ; OR tab. I am not sure what would be the delimiter out of these three. How to pass delimiter dynamically so data is loaded properly is my problem