# Reading a file with newlines as a tuple in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Is it possible to change the record delimiter from newline to some other string so as to read a file with newlines into a single tuple in pig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
A = LOAD '...' USING PigStorage(',') AS (...); //comma is the delimeter for fields
SET textinputformat.record.delimiter '<delimeter>'; // record delimeter, by default it is `\n`. You can change to any delimeter.
```

Comment: Never tried `EOF` as delimiter. Give it a try and let us know:) .BTW, whenever I wanted to read whole file I used to give first line of the as delimiter (assuming it will not repeat again in same file).

Comment: Awesome @iLoveCamelCase!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26357152/3831557)

You can use PigStorage

```
A = LOAD '/some/path/COMMA-DELIM-PREFIX*' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:chararray, ...);
B = LOAD '/some/path/SEMICOLON-DELIM-PREFIX*' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (f1:chararray, ...);
```

You can even try writing [load/store](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/udf.html#Load%2FStore+Functions) UDF.

There is java code example for both load and store.

**Load Functions** : LoadFunc abstract class has the main methods for loading data and for most use cases it would suffice to extend it. You can read more [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/udf.html#Load+Functions)

Example

> The loader implementation in the example is a loader for text data
>   with line delimiter as '\n' and '\t' as default field delimiter (which
>   can be overridden by passing a different field delimiter in the
>   constructor) - this is similar to current PigStorage loader in Pig.
>   The implementation uses an existing Hadoop supported Inputformat -
>   TextInputFormat - as the underlying InputFormat.

```
public class SimpleTextLoader extends LoadFunc {
    protected RecordReader in = null;
    private byte fieldDel = '\t';
    private ArrayList<Object> mProtoTuple = null;
    private TupleFactory mTupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

    public SimpleTextLoader() {
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a Pig loader that uses specified character as a field delimiter.
     *
     * @param delimiter
     *            the single byte character that is used to separate fields.
     *            ("\t" is the default.)
     */
    public SimpleTextLoader(String delimiter) {
        this();
        if (delimiter.length() == 1) {
            this.fieldDel = (byte)delimiter.charAt(0);
        } else if (delimiter.length() >  1 & & delimiter.charAt(0) == '\\') {
            switch (delimiter.charAt(1)) {
            case 't':
                this.fieldDel = (byte)'\t';
                break;

            case 'x':
               fieldDel =
                    Integer.valueOf(delimiter.substring(2), 16).byteValue();
               break;

            case 'u':
                this.fieldDel =
                    Integer.valueOf(delimiter.substring(2)).byteValue();
                break;

            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown delimiter " + delimiter);
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("PigStorage delimeter must be a single character");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Tuple getNext() throws IOException {
        try {
            boolean notDone = in.nextKeyValue();
            if (!notDone) {
                return null;
            }
            Text value = (Text) in.getCurrentValue();
            byte[] buf = value.getBytes();
            int len = value.getLength();
            int start = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (buf[i] == fieldDel) {
                    readField(buf, start, i);
                    start = i + 1;
                }
            }
            // pick up the last field
            readField(buf, start, len);

            Tuple t =  mTupleFactory.newTupleNoCopy(mProtoTuple);
            mProtoTuple = null;
            return t;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            int errCode = 6018;
            String errMsg = "Error while reading input";
            throw new ExecException(errMsg, errCode,
                    PigException.REMOTE_ENVIRONMENT, e);
        }

    }

    private void readField(byte[] buf, int start, int end) {
        if (mProtoTuple == null) {
            mProtoTuple = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }

        if (start == end) {
            // NULL value
            mProtoTuple.add(null);
        } else {
            mProtoTuple.add(new DataByteArray(buf, start, end));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public InputFormat getInputFormat() {
        return new TextInputFormat();
    }

    @Override
    public void prepareToRead(RecordReader reader, PigSplit split) {
        in = reader;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLocation(String location, Job job)
            throws IOException {
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, location);
    }
}
```

**Store Functions** : StoreFunc abstract class has the main methods for storing data and for most use cases it should suffice to extend it

Example

> The storer implementation in the example is a storer for text data
>   with line delimiter as '\n' and '\t' as default field delimiter (which
>   can be overridden by passing a different field delimiter in the
>   constructor) - this is similar to current PigStorage storer in Pig.
>   The implementation uses an existing Hadoop supported OutputFormat -
>   TextOutputFormat as the underlying OutputFormat.

```
public class SimpleTextStorer extends StoreFunc {
    protected RecordWriter writer = null;

    private byte fieldDel = '\t';
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    private static final String UTF8 = "UTF-8";
    public PigStorage() {
    }

    public PigStorage(String delimiter) {
        this();
        if (delimiter.length() == 1) {
            this.fieldDel = (byte)delimiter.charAt(0);
        } else if (delimiter.length() > 1delimiter.charAt(0) == '\\') {
            switch (delimiter.charAt(1)) {
            case 't':
                this.fieldDel = (byte)'\t';
                break;

            case 'x':
               fieldDel =
                    Integer.valueOf(delimiter.substring(2), 16).byteValue();
               break;
            case 'u':
                this.fieldDel =
                    Integer.valueOf(delimiter.substring(2)).byteValue();
                break;

            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown delimiter " + delimiter);
            }
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("PigStorage delimeter must be a single character");
        }
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream mOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream(BUFFER_SIZE);

    @Override
    public void putNext(Tuple f) throws IOException {
        int sz = f.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
            Object field;
            try {
                field = f.get(i);
            } catch (ExecException ee) {
                throw ee;
            }

            putField(field);

            if (i != sz - 1) {
                mOut.write(fieldDel);
            }
        }
        Text text = new Text(mOut.toByteArray());
        try {
            writer.write(null, text);
            mOut.reset();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void putField(Object field) throws IOException {
        //string constants for each delimiter
        String tupleBeginDelim = "(";
        String tupleEndDelim = ")";
        String bagBeginDelim = "{";
        String bagEndDelim = "}";
        String mapBeginDelim = "[";
        String mapEndDelim = "]";
        String fieldDelim = ",";
        String mapKeyValueDelim = "#";

        switch (DataType.findType(field)) {
        case DataType.NULL:
            break; // just leave it empty

        case DataType.BOOLEAN:
            mOut.write(((Boolean)field).toString().getBytes());
            break;

        case DataType.INTEGER:
            mOut.write(((Integer)field).toString().getBytes());
            break;

        case DataType.LONG:
            mOut.write(((Long)field).toString().getBytes());
            break;

        case DataType.FLOAT:
            mOut.write(((Float)field).toString().getBytes());
            break;

        case DataType.DOUBLE:
            mOut.write(((Double)field).toString().getBytes());
            break;

        case DataType.BYTEARRAY: {
            byte[] b = ((DataByteArray)field).get();
            mOut.write(b, 0, b.length);
            break;
                                 }

        case DataType.CHARARRAY:
            // oddly enough, writeBytes writes a string
            mOut.write(((String)field).getBytes(UTF8));
            break;

        case DataType.MAP:
            boolean mapHasNext = false;
            Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)field;
            mOut.write(mapBeginDelim.getBytes(UTF8));
            for(Map.Entry<String, Object> e: m.entrySet()) {
                if(mapHasNext) {
                    mOut.write(fieldDelim.getBytes(UTF8));
                } else {
                    mapHasNext = true;
                }
                putField(e.getKey());
                mOut.write(mapKeyValueDelim.getBytes(UTF8));
                putField(e.getValue());
            }
            mOut.write(mapEndDelim.getBytes(UTF8));
            break;

        case DataType.TUPLE:
            boolean tupleHasNext = false;
            Tuple t = (Tuple)field;
            mOut.write(tupleBeginDelim.getBytes(UTF8));
            for(int i = 0; i < t.size(); ++i) {
                if(tupleHasNext) {
                    mOut.write(fieldDelim.getBytes(UTF8));
                } else {
                    tupleHasNext = true;
                }
                try {
                    putField(t.get(i));
                } catch (ExecException ee) {
                    throw ee;
                }
            }
            mOut.write(tupleEndDelim.getBytes(UTF8));
            break;

        case DataType.BAG:
            boolean bagHasNext = false;
            mOut.write(bagBeginDelim.getBytes(UTF8));
            Iterator<Tuple> tupleIter = ((DataBag)field).iterator();
            while(tupleIter.hasNext()) {
                if(bagHasNext) {
                    mOut.write(fieldDelim.getBytes(UTF8));
                } else {
                    bagHasNext = true;
                }
                putField((Object)tupleIter.next());
            }
            mOut.write(bagEndDelim.getBytes(UTF8));
            break;

        default: {
            int errCode = 2108;
            String msg = "Could not determine data type of field: " + field;
            throw new ExecException(msg, errCode, PigException.BUG);
        }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public OutputFormat getOutputFormat() {
        return new TextOutputFormat<WritableComparable, Text>();
    }

    @Override
    public void prepareToWrite(RecordWriter writer) {
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void setStoreLocation(String location, Job job) throws IOException {
        job.getConfiguration().set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", "");
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(location));
        if (location.endsWith(".bz2")) {
            FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, true);
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job,  BZip2Codec.class);
        }  else if (location.endsWith(".gz")) {
            FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, true);
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job, GzipCodec.class);
        }
    }
}
```