# How to process multi - delimiter file in pig 0.8

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have input text file( name **multidelimiter**)  with followings records

```
1,Mical,2000;10
2,Smith,3000;20
```

I have written pig code as follows

```
A =LOAD '/user/input/multidelimiter' AS line;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN( REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL( line,'(.*)[,](.*)[,](.*)[;]')) AS (f1,f2,f3,f4);
```

But this code in not work given following error

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 1, column 78.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "\'(.*)[,](.*)[,](.*)[;"
```

I refereed following links but not able to resolve my error

[how to load files with different delimiter each time in piglatin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354949/how-to-load-files-with-different-delimiter-each-time-in-piglatin)

Please help me get out from this error.

Thanks.

Comment: The Pig syntax parser is reaching the semicolon and then thinking that the line has finished. You need a way of escaping the semicolon, but I'm afraid I don't know how to do that. A leading backslash maybe? `'(.*)[,](.*)[,](.*)[\;]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got solution.

Here is my solution:

```
A =LOAD '/user/input/multidelimiter' using PigStorage(',') as (empid,ename,line);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE empid,ename, FLATTEN( REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL( line,'(.*)\\u003B(.*)')) AS (sal:int,deptno:int);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for your input example:
LOAD as comma separated, than [STRSPLIT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#STRSPLIT) by ';' and FLATTEN