# Pig Latin Loading a file that has ! as delimiter

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-pig

I am new to Pig so there may be a simple solution but I am not able to figure it out.

Problem:  I have a flat file that has `!` as delimiter so the structure of the file looks something like this

```
!id!value!value2
!1!100!200
```

When I try to load this file using `pigstorage('\t')` everything is loaded into the first variable.

```
 foo=load'bar.txt' using Pigstorage('\t') as 
 Id:chararray,value:chararray,value3:chararray;
```

This does not work as all of the file is read into the `ID` column.
I want to split the load so that each value is read in its proper column.

So far I tried the `customloader` which I found on [how to load files with different delimiter each time in piglatin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354949/how-to-load-files-with-different-delimiter-each-time-in-piglatin)

However, that does not work with `!` also.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try

```
foo=load'bar.txt' using Pigstorage('!') as 
 Id:chararray,value:chararray,value3:chararray;
```