# How to load CSV with different delimiter to a single Hadoop table

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

I'd like to populate a Hive table with multiple CSV files. The problem is that not all files have the same delimiter. On the table creation I can specify only one delimiter e.g. ~

```
create table status (type string, ...) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
with serdeproperties ("separatorChar" = "~")
STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

Is there a build in feature to Hive which allows multiple CSV delimiters? I know that those files could be standardize by Hadoop jobs before loading or based on the https://stackoverflow.com/a/26356592/2207078 I could use pig to do it but I'm looking for some build in functionality. Ideally I'd like to create the status table without specified delimiter and instruct Hive how columns are separated on LOAD.

Comment: I'm not sure how your answer should help me or others? What was the value added here?

Comment: Not an answer, a comment. I can think of 2 "solutions" off the top of my head, but do you even start to realize how bad it is?

Comment: Actually I don't. I can imagine that I have two vendors providing me with exactly the same information just in slightly different format (delimiter to be more precise). And why this is so bad if Hive stores loaded data internally anyway?

Comment: **(1)** In this made up use-case we can see the lack of two basic concepts  of data management - **_Integration_** and **_ETL_**. Data does not miraculously  appear in one's systems. **(2)** The pig "solution" that you mentioned is bound to work only in very specific use-cases.  **(3)** There is no such thing as "_stored...internally_" in hive and in any case the issue here is not how you store the data but how you read the data correctly in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Demo

**Data Files**

comma.txt

```
|Now|,I've,heard,there,was
a,secret,chord;,That,David 
played,||and||,it,,pleased
the,,,Lord;,
```

semicolon.txt

```
But;;you;don't;really 
|care|;for;music;do;||||| you |||||?
```

pipeline.txt

```
,It,|,goes,|,like,|,this,|,the, 
fourth|the|fifth|The|;minor n
fall|the|;major|lift|The
baffled|king||composing|hallelujah
```

---

**DDL**

```
create external table mytable 
(c1 string,c2 string,c3 string,c4 string,c5 string)
partitioned by (delim string)
;

alter table mytable set serdeproperties ('field.delim'=',');
alter table mytable add partition (delim='comma');  

alter table mytable set serdeproperties ('field.delim'=';');
alter table mytable add partition (delim='semicolon');

alter table mytable set serdeproperties ('field.delim'='|');
alter table mytable add partition (delim='pipeline');
```

Put the files in their matching directories

```
mytable
├── delim=comma
│   └── comma.txt
├── delim=pipeline
│   └── pipeline.txt
└── delim=semicolon
    └── semicolon.txt
```

---

```
select * from mytable
;
```

---

```
+---------+---------+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------+
|   c1    |   c2    |   c3   |    c4     |        c5        |   delim   |
+---------+---------+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------+
| |Now|   | I've    | heard  | there     | was              | comma     |
| a       | secret  | chord; | That      | David            | comma     |
| played  | ||and|| | it     |           | pleased          | comma     |
| the     |         |        | Lord;     |                  | comma     |
| But     |         | you    | don't     | really           | semicolon |
| |care|  | for     | music  | do        | ||||| you |||||? | semicolon |
| ,It,    | ,goes,  | ,like, | ,this,    | ,the,            | pipeline  |
| fourth  | the     | fifth  | The       | ;minor           | pipeline  |
| fall    | the     | ;major | lift      | The              | pipeline  |
| baffled | king    |        | composing | hallelujah       | pipeline  |
+---------+---------+--------+-----------+------------------+-----------+
```